# Django: IndexError: tuple index out of range on sending a JQuery POST request

Tags: jquery, python, django, python-2.7

I have a use case wherein I'm sending some data using POST request to a URL, which is mapped to a view which then returns a success status.

JQuery

```
$( "#submit-id-add-update-user-button" ).click(function() 
    {   
        first_name = $('input[name="first_name"]').val();
        last_name = $('input[name="last_name"]').val();
        age = $('input[name="age"]').val();
        dob = $('input[name="dob"]').val();
        place = $('input[name="location"]').val();
        mobile = $('input[name="mobile"]').val();
        email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
        user_id = $('input[name="user_id"]').val();
        new_user = (user_id == '') ? ('yes') : ('no');

        var url = base_url + '/add-update-user/';
        var data = {
            'email': email,
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': last_name,
            'age': age,
            'dob': dob,
            'place': place,
            'mobile': mobile,
            'user_id': user_id,
            'new_user': new_user,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        };

        $.post( url, data)
          .done(function( data ) {
            console.log('this is done');
            window.location.href = "/";
        });

    });
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^add-update-user/', add_update_user, name="add_update_user")
```

views.py

```
def add_update_user(request):
    message = ''
    if(request.POST.get('new_user').encode('utf8') == 'yes'):
        usr = New_Users(first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
                last_name=request.POST.get('last_name'),age=request.POST.get('age'),dob=12345,
                location=request.POST.get('place'),mobile=request.POST.get('mobile'),
                email=request.POST.get('email'))
        usr.save()
        message = 'new user added'
    else:
        message = 'existing user updated'

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

However, this is the error that I'm encountering:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 861, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 734, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/home/manas/Python/Interviews/pricebaba_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 173, in format
    if args[1][0] == '2':
IndexError: tuple index out of range
Logged from file basehttp.py, line 85
```

I'm not really sure what this error means or why is it arising. Would really appreciate some help on this.

EDIT: I have updated my `views.py` code. The error seems to be arising from the insert query that I have used for the `New_Users` model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string to HttpResponse, not a dict.

Comment: when I use `return HttpResponse('success')` instead, I still get the same error.

Comment: I have edited my `views.py` file. The error seems to be arising from a query that I have used.